# Snap tutorial and advice

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Can anybody suggest me serious tutorial on Snap or book? Can you share your impressions about Snap? 
I have experience with web programming, but I started learn Haskell and it is great, so I want to wrote site using my new favorite language?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are definitely no books on Snap.  Like all Haskell web frameworks, it's in its early stages.

That said, Snap is a nice clean way to build web applications, and the documentation is very good.  Visit http://snapframework.com and click the documentation link.  There are tutorials for both Snap itself, and the Heist template engine.  There's also a link in the download section to the Snap framework's own web site as a Snap application, which is fairly clean, and a decent way to learn about building simple web applications in Snap.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Happstack](http://happstack.com/docs) and Yesod have been around a while. [Yesod](http://docs.yesodweb.com/) has a good number of tutorials and screencasts, as well as extensive (though not yet completed) documentation http://docs.yesodweb.com/book/.